# Auto slash(/) for date input using Javascript MM/YY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on an input form that includes a credit card expiration date for only Visa and Mastercard. These two restrict the expiration date to MM/YY. I'm using the following script elsewhere on the form to automatically introduce slashes as the user types in their birth date:

```
$(function() {
     var date = document.getElementById('ccexp');
     function checkValue(str, max) {
       if (str.charAt(0) !== '0' || str == '00') {
         var num = parseInt(str);
         if (isNaN(num) || num <= 0 || num > max) num = 1;
         str = num > parseInt(max.toString().charAt(0)) && num.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + num : num.toString();
       }
       return str;
     }

     date.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
       this.type = 'text';
       var input = this.value;
       var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;

       if (key == 8 || key == 46)    // checks if backspace or delete is being pressed
         return false;

       if (/\D\/$/.test(input)) input = input.substr(0, input.length - 1);
       var values = input.split('/').map(function(v) {
         return v.replace(/\D/g, '')
       });

       if (values[0]) values[0] = checkValue(values[0], 12);  // validates month 1-12
       if (values[1]) values[1] = checkValue(values[1], 31); // validates day 1-31
       var output = values.map(function(v, i) {
         return v.length == 2 && i < 2 ? v + '/' : v;
       });
       this.value = output.join('').substr(0, 10);
     });
});
```

(The requirements on this project are for users to type in dates, rather than use a date picker). I'd like to use a version of this script to look for MM/YY, but I really don't know how to parse this well enough myself.

Comment: May I ask why `// validates day 1-31` exists? You are only interested in MM/YY, right?

Comment: I'm using this script in another field in the form to collect date of birth, and I am hoping to modify it to collect MM/YY for something unrelated.

Comment: I'm not married to using this script by any means. I just need a way to validated MM/YY and auto-populate the slash as the user types.